# Azure Data factory changing Azure Table schema

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-factory

I am planning to use Azure Data factory for creating backup of Azure Tables storage. The entities in my Azure Table could change their schema. Is there a way Azure Pipeline could handle this without a manual intervention everytime schema changes ?

Eg : Let first entry be

```
  <entry>
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:PartitionKey>P1</d:PartitionKey>
        <d:RowKey>R1</d:RowKey>
        <d:Timestamp m:type="Edm.DateTime">2017-05-22T20:37:34.8743000Z</d:Timestamp>
        <d:IsDefault m:type="Edm.Boolean">False</d:IsDefault>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
```

While another entry could be :

```
  <entry>
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:PartitionKey>P2</d:PartitionKey>
        <d:RowKey>R2</d:RowKey>
        <d:Timestamp m:type="Edm.DateTime">2017-05-22T20:37:34.8743000Z</d:Timestamp>
        <d:IsDefault m:type="Edm.Boolean">False</d:IsDefault>
        **<d:IsTest m:type="Edm.Boolean">False</d:IsTest>**
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
```

I don't want to change my Dataset everytime a entity change.

> According to doc :
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-faq
>
> If the structure and jsonPathDefinition are not defined in the Data
>   Factory dataset, the Copy Activity detects the schema from the first
>   object and flatten the whole object.

Is their a workaround to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

> The entities in my Azure Table could change their schema. Is there a way Azure Pipeline could handle this without a manual intervention everytime schema changes ?

In [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-azure-table-connector#dataset-properties), we could find that for schema-free data stores such as Azure Table, the Data Factory service infers the schema in one of the following ways:

*1. If you specify the structure of data by using the structure property in the dataset definition, the Data Factory service honors this structure as the schema. In this case, if a row does not contain a value for a column, a null value is provided for it.*

*2. If you don't specify the structure of data by using the structure property in the dataset definition, Data Factory infers the schema by using the first row in the data. In this case, if the first row does not contain the full schema, some columns are missed in the result of copy operation.*

If you do not want to manually and explicitly specify the structure property in the dataset definition, you could store/update the table schema in another table or blob when schema changes, and then you could [create custom activity by using .NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-copy-activity-tutorial-using-dotnet-api) and dynamically&programmatically define structure property based on the stored schema when you create datasets.

Comment: Somehow that means that Copy Activity is forcing schema on a NoSQL, which makes very little sense to me.

Comment: I just finished copying 42 Azure data tables from one storage account to another when I noticed that some of the destination tables were missing columns.  This is very frustrating to me because I don't want to explicitly specify the schema for 42 tables.  You would think that Microsoft would infer the schema by all the actual possible columns in the table and not by just looking at the first row.  Ugghhh!