# Mapping tab in ADF "Copy data" action missing new table storage property/column name

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-table-storage

We have an existing Azure Data Factory pipeline that takes data from Azure Table Storage table and copies the data to Azure SQL table - which is working without issue.
The problem exists when we added a new data element to the table storage (since it is NoSQL). When I go into the ADF Source of Pipeline and refresh the table storage, the new data is not available to map properly. Is there something I am missing to get this new data element (column) to show up. I know this is working correctly since I can see this column in Azure Storage Explorer.

Comment: could you show us any screenshots?If you add a new element to source, did you change the sink Azure SQL schema? Or they couldn't be mapped.

Comment: I located the answer with additional research. See article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44123539/azure-data-factory-changing-azure-table-schema

Comment: Hi @user2047969, very glad to hear that! I just help you post it as the answer. You can  accept it as answer and the question won't be closed. This also can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations that you found the answer:

"I located the answer with additional research. See article: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44123539/azure-data-factory-changing-azure-table-schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44123539/azure-data-factory-changing-azure-table-schema%22)

This can be beneficial to other community members.